# CDF of $M(X,Y)$?

Tags: probability, distributions, independence, uniform-distribution

Let $X,Y \sim^{\text{iid}} Unif(0,1)$. Let $M = M(X,Y) = \min\{X,Y,1-Y,1-X,|X-Y|,1-|X-Y|\}$. Supposedly $image(M) \subseteq (0,\frac13)$ and distribution of $M$ is $F_M(m)= (3m(2-3m))1_{(0,\frac13)}(m) + 1_{(\frac13,\infty)}(m)$.

**Question**: How do I compute the CDF of $M$? Below is what I've tried so far.

Well $|X-Y| \ge m$ and $1-|X-Y| \ge m$ tells me $m \le |X-Y| \le 1-m$. So it looks like I have 4 cases

1. $x+(m-1) \le y \le x-m$
2. $x+m \le y$
3. $y \le x-m$
4. $x-(m-1) \le y \le x+m$ (but I think I rule out this last case because here I have $m \ge \frac12$.

Then $X,Y,1-Y,1-X \ge m$ tells me $m \le X \le 1-m$ and $m \le Y \le 1-m$. So I guess the 3 cases become

1. $x+m-1 = \max\{m,x+m-1\} \le y \le \min\{x-m,1-m\} = x-m$
2. $x+m = \max\{m,x+m\} \le y \le 1-m$
3. $m \le y \le \min\{x-m,1-m\} = x-m$

But it seems if I do $\int_0^1 \int_{\cdot}^{\cdot} 1 dy dx$ for each case and then add them up I get only $2-6m$.

Comment: Cross-post: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4065080/321264.

Answer (score 3):

**As always, begin by drawing a picture.**

[image: Figure 1: full contour plot]

The answer is *immediate* just by glancing at this figure and requires almost no calculation.  I will explain--but the explanation takes much longer than finding the answer!

Because $(X,Y)$ has a uniform distribution, the value of the CDF at any height $z=\min(x,y,1-y,1-x,|x-y|,1-|x-y|)$ is proportional to the area of the points *not* enclosed by the level-$z$ contour.

**The plot suggests there is a 6-fold symmetry group in play.**  We can exploit it by choosing a representative of each coset.  I have chosen to use the triangle $ABC.$  (This is where $y$ is the smallest of the six values $x,$ $y,$ *etc.*  The other five regions correspond to the places where any given one of those six values is the smallest.)

For instance, given any $(x,y)$ in the unit square,

1. If $x \le y$ (a location in the upper left set of contours), then $(y,x)$ is in the lower right half of the unit square and $z(y,x)=z(x,y).$
2. Given we have arranged that $x \ge y,$ find the smallest value among the *nonnegative* numbers $y,$ $x-y,$ and $1-x.$  Since their average is $(y+(x-y)+(1-x))/3 = 1/3,$ the smallest must lie between $0$ and $1/3.$  Now:

   - If $y$ is the smallest, do nothing.
   - If $x-y$ is the smallest, replace $(x,y)$ by $(1-y,x-y).$
   - Otherwise (when $1-x$ is smallest), replace $(x,y)$ by $(1-(x-y), 1-x).$

   You can easily verify this preserves the value of $z,$ because (based on step $(1)$) the smallest value among $x,$ $y,$ $\ldots,$ $1-|x-y|$ does not change.  In the preceding figure, these operations are merely rotating the vertices $(0,0),$ $(1,0),$ and $(1,1)$ among themselves, corresponding to a (generalized) order-three rotation of that triangle (with $A$ as its center).

Steps $(1)$ and $(2)$ preserve the value of $z$ and map the unit square in a six-to-one fashion into the triangle $ABC$ (a *fundamental domain* of the group).    Here is a detail of the values of $z$ within this fundamental domain.  Since we have arranged to make $y=z,$ they are all horizontal and equally spaced with heights equal to $z:$

[image: Figure 2: detail of contours in the fundamental domain]

Because all contours enclose similar triangular regions (with apex $A$) and heights $1/3-z,$ it is now obvious that the relative area *above* any value $z,$ where $0\le z\le 1/3,$ is proportional to the square of the height $1/3-z.$  Consequently the CDF (which is the complementary probability) must take the form

$$F_Z(z) = 1 - C(1/3-z)^2.$$

Since $F_Z(0)=0,$ the only possible value for the normalizing constant is $C=9$ (this is the only calculation needed to solve this problem!) and

> $$F_Z(z) = 1 - 9(1/3-z)^2.$$

Here is a histogram of the $z$-values of the pixels used in the two figures, on which I have superimposed a plot of the density $\mathrm{d}/\mathrm{d}z\,F_Z(z) = 18(1/3-z):$

[image: Figure 3]

Their agreement is near-perfect.

Comment: Thanks whuber♦! Also, re 'As always, begin by drawing a picture.', i posted an answer. please let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's what I did on wolfram:

By trying out values of $m=\frac15, \frac16, \frac17$ (Btw: $\frac14$ was kind of an outlier. **See below** re 'only issue'. Also, as expected, $\frac13$ gave no solutions), I got 4 cases

1. $x \in (m,2m)$, $y \in (x+m,1-m)$
2. $x \in (2m,1-2m)$, $y \in (m, x-m)$
3. $x \in (2m,1-2m)$, $y \in (x+m, 1-m)$
4. $x \in (1-2m,1-m)$, $y \in (m,x-m)$

When sketching this, I ended up getting 4 trapezoid figures.

Anyhoo, I got

1. $\int_m^{2m} \int_{x+m}^{1-m} 1 dy dx$
2. $\int_{2m}^{1-2m} \int_{m}^{x-m} 1 dy dx$
3. $\int_{2m}^{1-2m} \int_{x+m}^{1-m} 1 dy dx$
4. $\int_{1-2m}^{1-m} \int_{m}^{x-m} 1 dy dx$
5. Combining (1) and (3), we get $\int_m^{1-2m} \int_{x+m}^{1-m} 1 dy dx$
6. Combining (2) and (4), we get $\int_{2m}^{1-m} \int_{x+m}^{1-m} 1 dy dx$
7. Combining (5) and (6) we get our desired distribution.

**My one issue however** is the very fact that we say $(2m,1-2m)$ in the first place suggests $m \in (0,\frac14)$ only! (**See above** re 'outlier'.) I mean, I don't think $2m$ and $1-2m$ should be compared, but I think $m$ and $1-m$ should be compared.

I think this can be fixed if we just do 2 cases

1. $x \in (m,1-2m)$, $y \in (x+m,1-m)$, combining (1) and (3)
2. $x \in (2m,1-m)$, $y \in (m, x-m)$, combining (2) and (4)